# why when i try system("cd PATH"); , terminal can't go to my path

Tags: c, terminal

i have a trouble with :

```
system("cd mypath");
```

when i try this in C programming language terminal doesn't do anything.
i need help.

Comment: you launch an instance of `/bin/sh` justo to make it change its current dir to `mypath`, and then `exit(2)`.   Nothing happens in your process.... To change directories, there's a system call `chdir(2)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

look just do

```
chdir("path");
```

or

```
system("chdir PATH"); //linux
```

Answer (score 10):

The `system` function creates a whole new process, separate from the one calling the function.

Each process have its own current working directory associated with it, and this working directory is specific to that process only. Changing the working directory of one process will not change it for another process.

If you want to change the working directory of your own process use operating-system specific functions to to it. Like [`chdir`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/chdir.2.html) on Linux (and other POSIX system like macOS), or [`SetCurrentDirectory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-setcurrentdirectory) in Windows.

---

Note that if you change directory in your own process, the directory of the shell or console that invoked your program will not be changed, as it's also a separate process from yours.

Comment: can you give me a example?

Comment: @someoneidontwanttosay `if (chdir("mypath") == -1){ /* error it failed */ } else { /* success */ }`

Comment: Re “Changing the directory in an unrelated process will of course not change the directory in your own process”: This reveals an epistemological error. The “of course” does not logically follow from the information at hand. **You** have a mental model of processes in which a “working directory” is associated with each process. **The OP** does not have that model, and it is not obvious it is a logical necessity. An operating system **could** associate a working directory with a login session. So the design of the “working directory” has to be explained to OP.

Comment: #include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <string.h>
void nodder(void);
int main(){
 nodder();
 return 0;
}
void nodder(void){
 for(;;){
  char cwd[PATH_MAX];
  if (getcwd(cwd, sizeof(cwd)) != NULL) {
   char itx[90];
   printf("<-XSHELL->%s>apt==> ", cwd);
   fgets(itx, 90, stdin);
   if(strcmp(itx, "mkC\n")==0){
    system("clear");
   }
   else if(strcmp(itx, "go\n")==0){
    char targ[20];
    printf("<>DIRECTORY OR FOLDER: ");
    fgets(targ, 20, stdin);
    system("cd ", targ);
   }
   else{
    printf("Failed\n");
   }
 }
}
}

Comment: @someoneidontwanttosay If you want to create a shell-like program then please take some time to research the basic concepts behind it first, like processes and working directories. Learning by trial-and-error is not going to work long-term.

Comment: look i just want build very simple and easy shell

Comment: but im a java developer and im new in c

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude i resolve it printf("Connot go in another directory.using full path for needed times(i.e  /home/user/...)\n"); :\ thanks for your idea :|